# Cannot submit applications, page just refreshes

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I cannot submit any applications on the Jobs site.  I fill out all the information, attach my resume, and when I click the submit button, the page just refreshes.  I don't see any error messages, and I don't get the confirmation email.

It started yesterday morning about 9am Eastern.

I am on Windows 10 and latest Chrome.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the apply button launched a modal dialog or whether it navigated to a new page?

Comment: @DeanWard - New page.  It worked once or twice on the new page yesterday, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the report, fix and an answer with more details on its way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're running an A/B test on a new full page apply process and you fell into the 'new' side of the experiment. Due to an oversight this page was missing the logic needed to handle captchas when a threshold of applications has been reached within a certain timeframe.

I've made sure all that is present and things are now functioning correctly. When you next apply you'll likely see the 'Not a Robot' prompt. Check that box and you should be good to go.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the heads up!

Comment: So you're saying I'm applying to too many jobs? :)  That worked! Thanks for the quick turnaround. Btw, I didn't get a captcha.

Comment: You probably just dropped below the threshold...